# Matlab network s2sdd for s-parameters in python

Tags: python, matlab

I am converting a code from Matlab to python.
In Matlab an s4p file (s-parameters of a 4 port network) is read and then the s-parameters of 4 single ports are converted to s-parameters of 2 differential ports using s2sdd method.
I am using skrt (scikit-rf) in python to read in the s4p file but I am stuck when converting the s-parameters. Is there a method doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I ported the s2sdd from matlab to python. I could not find a suitable existing method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mixed mode s-parameter conversion equation.
then, you can extract 1p -2p matrix
or, you can use scikit-rf easily

https://scikit-rf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/mixedmodeanalysis/Mixed%20Mode%20Basics.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30543310)